# Direct edit on selected label in eclipse gef

Tags: eclipse-gef

I have two labels in an figure . by default gef allows direct editing to be performed when the user clicks the edit part. I have two labels in the same figure i have to perform direct editing on the label on which the mouse was clicked . but now when i click both the labels are displaying for direct edit ?

i have placed the coding

```
@Override
public void performRequest( final Request req )
{

if( req.getType().equals( RequestConstants.REQ_OPEN ) || req.getType().equals( RequestConstants.REQ_DIRECT_EDIT ) )
{

perform directedi()
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain me that how you are displaying labels for direct edit.I have single lable in figure & i want to make it editable whenever double click is performed in figure

Answer (score 2):

you can try to read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-editor/gef-schema-editor.html) article: direct edit is one of the topics
Moreover [this](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/sg246302.html?Open) is another intresting resource about gef development

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it, but my guess is that either you have to either create an editpart for each label and then each editpart will get the REQ_DIRECT request, or you can plug directly a draw2d listener to the label and create more specific requests.
The first option can be implemented by returning from the containing figure two model children that you can probably store at the parent. The factory should be able go identify them and create a new edit part which in turn creates a figure that only contains a label and which installs the direct edit policy
I don't know how to implement the second solution :-)